Converting Line Segments to Lines
Is there a simple way to break a Line comprising multiple line segments, into separate Lines? Or am I going about this wrong? (Or both?)

TL;DR
A notebook uses FindImageShapes[img, "LineSegment"]; in efforts to determine the attitude of a rocket.

From a frame of the Starship IFT-6 live stream. The purple section shows the booster's angle.
The lines might be of this general form, where some are lines of 2 points, while others are lines made of a number of line segments (each having 2 points):
{Line[{{{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {4, .5}}}],Line[{{{2, 1.2}, {1, .6}}}]}


This is functionally equivalent to:
l1 = Line[{{{1, 0}, {3, 1}}}];
l2 = Line[{{{3, 1}, {4, .5}}}];
l3 = Line[{{{2, 1.2}, {1, .6}}}];


I need to get the angle of the longest line, the red one. If the original line segments were in an array of simple lines like the second group of three, I could easily iterate it to check the length and proceed from there. But I have not succeeded in either transforming the data from one form to the other or navigating the data in its original form.

lines = {Line[{{{1, 0}, {3, 1}}, {{3, 1}, {4, .5}}}], 
   Line[{{{2, 1.2}, {1, .6}}}]};

MeshPrimitives[
 DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[lines], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞],
  1]


{Line[{{1., 0.}, {3., 1.}}], Line[{{3., 1.}, {4., 0.5}}],  Line[{{1., 0.6}, {2., 1.2}}]}

